# Try to create new project with INET reference, got : "unexpected NAME, expecting $end" in .msg file

Tags: omnet++, inet

I created a project which contains my linklayer and simulation source code.
This project has INET as the project reference.

At build time, I got this error:

> Error: syntax error, unexpected NAME, expecting $end

It comes from the message file (which contains types of messages):

```
import inet.common.INETDefs;
```

My message file is very similar to the Bmac message file (also tried with Bmac, got the same error).

Any idea please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INET 4.X` uses a new version of message compiler. But `OMNeT++` by default sets in new project the old one.
In your project go to `Properties`, select `OMNeT++` | `Makemake` | src folder | `Options...` | `Custom` and add the following line:

```
MSGC:=$(MSGC) --msg6
```

Comment: Thank you,
I'm facing other errors :

`cannot resolve import 'inet.common.INETDefs'`
`cannot resolve import 'inet.linklayer.base.MacHeaderBase`

It comes from :

`import inet.common.INETDefs;`
`import inet.linklayer.base.MacHeaderBase;`

Knowing that INET is the project reference, I have no more idea...