# error: syntax error, unexpected NAME, expecting $end in OMNET++?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I need to add a .msg file to my project. The .msg code is :

```
import inet.common.INETDefs;
import inet.common.packet.chunk.Chunk;
import inet.networklayer.contract.ipv4.Ipv4Address;

namespace inet;

class HelloMsg extends FieldsChunk
{
    Ipv4Address srcAddress; 
    unsigned int sequencenumber;
    int hopdistance; 
}
```

When I build my project, I get this error:

> syntax error, unexpected NAME, expecting $end.

Comment: Possible duplicate. Take a look at [Try to create new project with INET reference, got : “unexpected NAME, expecting $end” in .msg file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56005709/try-to-create-new-project-with-inet-reference-got-unexpected-name-expecting)

Comment: Thank you, the solution in the link you post solved my problem.

Comment: You are welcome. You may vote up the solution that helps you - it helps others find the best answer.

Comment: I did, thanks again.